# how to skip % sign on jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, el, aem

here is the code, i want all space string to be replaced by '%20':

the problem is... its html source displays like this ->

it is currently skipping all my '%' signs...
and what I expected to get is something like this (the 'TOP%20NAV' is hard code, ignore it plz) -->

=====================================================================================

here s the code producing the url:

any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In strings when formatting replace single `%` with double `%%` to escape the percent sign.

Comment: i just updated code , please check the modified version. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<c:out value="${title}"/>
```

This will HTML-encode the string.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think Balaji's solution might be the way to go, however here is another option.

I have run into this same issue before and ended up using the html entity in place of the % sign.  For example:

```
<c:set var="level1PageTitleFormat" value="${fn:replace(level1Page.title,' ','&#37;20')
```

This should get the job done for you.